# Firebase multi path query takes long to response

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, callback

I am using firebase realtime database and I have a multi path firebase update query that I was using for a while, however for last couple of days the callback never fires and other firebase database requests are blocked as well until this one fires. Callback takes incredibly longer to fire than it should or it used to. And most interestingly this issue does happen on Windows environment only.

```
 let updateObj = {}
 updateObj[`transcripts/${uid}/${itemId}/currentState`] = currentState
 updateObj[`lists/${uid}/${itemId}/edited`] = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
 updateObj[`lists/${uid}/${itemId}/filename`] = title
 db.ref().update(updateObj, function(error){
      //handle error
 }
```

I thought it could possibly be because another reference is initialized at the same path later on but callback sometimes hangs even before that.

```
 updateObj[`transcripts/${uid}/${itemId}/currentState`] = currentState
```

variable currentstate above has a somewhat of a big array node inside so I also think the array might be the issue considering they don't really work that efficiently with firebase realtime database.

Commenting this out solves all the problem but I am still clueless how this suddenly started to break firebase realtime database for me.